# I need to delete rows that are newer than 2019

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am sending files from 12 years back to the server. For some reason, 2019 did not transfer in full and I have to remove it from DB.
How to delete rows younger than 2018-12-30?

I try code below but i get error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETE"
LINE 2: DELETE * FROM mlode WHERE "kd" > DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 12, 31)
        ^
SQL state: 42601
```

And this is code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE * FROM mlode WHERE "kd" > DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 12, 31)
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Any one knows what is wrong?

Ok I make progres. I changed the code to:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM mlode WHERE kd >= DATE '2019-01-01';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

But now i get this error:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Problem solved Thanks for help.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You should always ag your SQL requests with your DBMS. And what exactly is the problem you are facing? What exactly keeps you from writing the delete statement. have you tried anything and failed? Where did you fail?

Comment: And why do you want to remove rows younger than 2018-12-30? Why do you want to remove 2018-12-31?

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner I am using postgresql and PgAdmin4 for management. You have right i should remove records from 2018-12-31.

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find `DATEFROMPARTS()`

Comment: There must be another error message _before_ the "transaction is aborted" message - that one tells you what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `DELETE * FROM`, but `DELETE FROM`.

```
DELETE FROM mlode WHERE kd >= DATE '2019-01-01';
```

Comment: Ok i change this lane but i get the same error. Like something is wrong with "DELETE"

Comment: Thanks for help. This code rly help me, I solve rest on my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE [DATEFIELD] > DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 12, 30)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: This syntax is very DBMS specific, and we don't know yet which DBMS the OP is using. Rather than using `DATEFROMPARTS` we would use a date literal in most DBMS.